# Creating a stand alone command line jar file

Tags: java, jar, binary

I have created a java program successful.
But while testing it on other pc I come after several problems cause-
I have used Java 9 and other pc have 10 different versions of java installed so it creates a mess while installing jdk 9.
So how can I create a jar file will all the jdk binary with it so that I don't have to install the jdk or jre in other pc

Comment: That will be a mess to package JRE to run the JAR

Comment: I exactly dont know dut i have gone through many programs like adobe office etc and they have their own java bin folder. I want to do something simmilar to it

Comment: That's part of what Jigar means by a mess, I think.  Now the user has 2 separate installations of Java on his hard-drive that need to be patched, etc.  Or 3, or 4 or ....

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming.  More about software compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javapackager that comes with your version of java.
Check the oracle documentation on this topic: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm

Comment: I don't know why this answer got down-voted -- it is the exact mechanism provided by Sun/Oracle for providing a self-contained Java executable. It is designed to solve the exact problem the OP described. Many people, including myself, aren't keen on distributing an entire run-time environment with application code; but that's the price that we pay for using a programming paradigm that _requires_ a run-time environment.